# NodeJS + Socket.io : can't send data to a specific room created by client

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I want client to create room X with my server. Then when an event occur, my server connect to room X and send data.

**server.js**

```
const https = require('https');
var tls = require('tls')
var fs = require('fs')

const SSLoptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

const server = https.createServer(SSLoptions, app).listen(8080);

const options = { /* ... */ };
const io = require("socket.io")(server, options);

io.on("connection", socket => { 
    socket.on('room', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log('. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . a user connected'+room);
        io.to(room).emit('message', 'TESTMESSAGE'+room);
    });
});


// This code works, my client receive "TESTMESSAGEroom1234"
```

**client.ejs**

```
var socket = io();

var room = 'room1234';

socket.on('connect', function() {
   socket.emit('room', room);
});

// I want to receive data
socket.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I do that, everything works, but if change my server.js like this :

**server.js that doesn't work**

```
const https = require('https');
var tls = require('tls')
var fs = require('fs')

const SSLoptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

const server = https.createServer(SSLoptions, app).listen(8080);

const options = { /* ... */ };
const io = require("socket.io")(server, options);


function event(data) {
io.on("connection", socket => { 
    socket.on('room', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log('. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . a user connected'+room);
        io.to(room).emit('message', 'what is going on, party people?'+room);
    });
  }
}


event(data);
// Nothing happen...
```

What is wrong with the code ? At initialization it's fine, but not in a function...